# Как передать данные из PendingIntent

Tags: java, android

У меня есть код в сервисе:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityFragments.class);
    intent.putExtra("ExamFragment","ExamFragment");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Уведомление");
            mBuilder.setContentText("Вам нужно срочно проверить результаты");

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
```

Это код вызывает уведомление.
Как мне сделать так: Записать некий ключ в PendingIntent и передать его активности(при нажатии на уведомление), и соответственно достать его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно помещать нужные данные в `Intent`, на основе которого создаётся ваш `PendingIntent`. Помещать нужно в `Bundle` интента. Делать это можно двумя способами:

1. Создать объект типа Bundle, наполнить его данными с помощью методов типа `Bundle#putString("key", "value")` и присвоить его интенту методом `Intent#putExtras(Bundle b)`
2. Поместить инфу в уже имеющийся `Bundle` интента методом `Intent#putExtra("key", value)` где `value` это примитив или объект, реализующий интерфейсы `Parcelable` или `Serializable`

Далее, после клика по уведомлению в вашем случае запустится актвити и будет вызван её метод `Activity#onNewIntent(Intent intent)` куда и придёт созданный и наполненный вами `Intent`, из которого вы можете получить записанные вами данные